# Displaying inputs based on previous selection

Tags: jquery, select

I have a page with several select inputs which take the following form

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <select class="selectpicker" name="productType" id="productType">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Cereal">Cereal</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is display select inputs only when the previous select has been selected.  To do this I am essentially doing

```
$( "#productType" ).change(function() {
   if($(this).val() != '') {
       $('#yearRow').css('display', 'block');
   } else {
       $('#yearRow').css('display', 'none');
   }
});
```

I have set up a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amry23ub/1/)

Although what I have works, I have a feeling it is going to get ugly.  Reason I say this is because if you select the first input, and then the second, and then unselect the first, the third input will remain.  I could handle the display of every input within every select change function, but this is where I think it will get messy.  Basically, I want to avoid this

```
$( "#productType" ).change(function() {
   if($(this).val() != '') {
       $('#yearRow').css('display', 'block');
   } else {
       $('#yearRow').css('display', 'none');
       $('#monthRow').css('display', 'none');
       $('#idRow').css('display', 'none');
       //Any other rows
   }
});
```

Is there a better way of doing what I am attempting to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

- Add some class to all the selects and their `row` parents.

Then you can use the select's class selector like this:

```
$( ".selectpicker" ).change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    //Display Next Select
    if ($this.val().toString().length) {
        $this.closest('div.select-parent').next('div.select-parent').removeClass('hiddenRow');
        return;
    }

    //Hide Next All Selects
    $this.closest('div.select-parent').nextAll('div.select-parent').addClass('hiddenRow')
       .find('select').val("").selectpicker('refresh'); //Refresh Select
});
```

Here is the [`FIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/amry23ub/3/).

Comment: That looks like a good solution.  I have noticed one thing though.  If you select the first, second and third, and then deselect the first, everything is removed as it should be.  However, if you then reselect the first, the second still has its previous value so to get the third to display you have to change its value twice.  Is there a way to reset their values?  Thanks